# grunt csscomb doesn't work

Tags: css, node.js

I compile *.less files into *.css files, using node,js and `grunt`, and then I need to change properties' order and create final css file, and for this task I tried to use [grunt-csscomb](https://github.com/csscomb/grunt-csscomb)

My `Gruntfile.js`

```
 module.exports = function (grunt) {

 grunt.initConfig({
     pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

     less: {
         development: {
             options: {
                 compress: false
             },
             files: {
                 "css/unsorted_style.css": "less/style.less"
             }
         }
     },

     csscomb: {
        foo: {
             files: {
                 'css/style.css': ['css/unsorted_style.css']
             }
        }
     },

     watch: {
         less: {
             files: ['less/*.less'],
             tasks: ['less'],
             options: {
                 spawn: false
             }
         },

         css {
            files: ['css/unsorted_style.css'],
            tasks: ['css', 'csscomb'],
            options: {
                 spawn: false
             }
         }

     }
 });

 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-csscomb');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

 grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'csscomb', 'watch']);

 };
```

but I get an error [image]

What's wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `:` in `css`

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

 grunt.initConfig({
     pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

     less: {
         development: {
             options: {
                 compress: false
             },
             files: {
                 "css/unsorted_style.css": "less/style.less"
             }
         }
     },

     csscomb: {
        foo: {
             files: {
                 'css/style.css': ['css/unsorted_style.css']
             }
        }
     },

     watch: {
         less: {
             files: ['less/*.less'],
             tasks: ['less'],
             options: {
                 spawn: false
             }
         },

         css: {
            files: ['css/unsorted_style.css'],
            tasks: ['css', 'csscomb'],
            options: {
                 spawn: false
             }
         }

     }
 });

 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-csscomb');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

 grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'csscomb', 'watch']);

 };
```